# How do cosmos DB calculate the Request Charge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

How do cosmos DB calculate the Request Charge (i.e Total request charge in Request Units per second (RU/s) per operation type.)

I ran a script that upserts a sample JSON every second and found weird metrics where my Request Charge was stated at over 1.5K

When I ran the same query on MONGO SHELL of COSMOS DB it returned me an RU of **2.31 RUs**

> db.cdrs.update( { record_key :"2088918ecc406535693a48a4f57viren" }, {"call_date":"2020-03-20T23:00:00Z","record_key":"2088918ecc406535693a48a4f57viren","cdr_filename":"NVX00322_alliance.cdr.zip","record_number":1,"source":"Cdr_Alliance10","callid":"2296J25CQ","switch":"10.0.1.11:4000","start_time_utc":"2020-03-20T23:15:13Z","end_time_utc":"2020-03-20T23:15:19Z","call_duration_seconds":6,"release_code":"200","from_number":"3205586312","to_number":"8774400565","bill_to_number":"2221738323     ","raw_cdr":{"authCode":"                ","calling_card_no":"          ","chargeNumber":"2221738323     ","cost":"0000000013","countryIndex":"0  ","dialAround":"0","duration":"000001","infoDigits":"00","messageId":"2296J25CQ","origCity":"WEATHER","origLata":"626","origNo":"3205586312","origNumber":"3205586312","origOcn":"1123","origState":"MN","payComp":"0","service":"8","startDate":"032020","startTime":"231513","termCity":"D TOLLFREE","termLata":"000","termNumber":"8774400565    ","termOcn":"0000","termState":"NJ","term_no":"2221738323     ","term_type":"0"}}, { upsert: true } )

```
Operation consumed 2.31 RUs
```

If I understand Cosmos(also mention in COSMOS) would not charge differently if the same operation is performed over and over again.

So by that

```
2.31 * 60 = 120 RU
```

That's 120 RU/minute still does not explain the 1.5K+ request charge(screenshot below) that COSMOS DB Metric shows.

[image]

```
cat NVX00322_alliance.cdr-1.json | wc -l
    1
```

The resultant code that upserts into cosmos DB is here

```
func main() { 
   handler, err := os.OpenFile("NVX00322_alliance.cdr-1.json", os.O_RDONLY, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var data map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(handler).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)

    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            if err := mongoUpload(data); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }
    }
}

func mongoUpload(data map[string]interface{}) error {
    fmt.Printf("\r %d", uploadCount)
    uploadCount++
    _, err := collection.Upsert(bson.M{"record_key": data["record_key"]}, data)
    if err != nil {
        if (err == io.EOF) || (strings.Contains(err.Error(), "read: connection reset by peer")) {
            mongoSetup()
        }
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

RUs allocate for the collection is MAX RU/s 21000 and Throughput is set to Automatic Scale.

The partition key is `call_date` but as I'm checking the collection(this specific collection) the total document in the given collection and DB is not more than 20 documents.

Comment: I'm guessing you're seeing the wrong RU for your upsert. The minimum for any write would be 5, in practice 10 even for small items.

Comment: It is true that the same operation will cost the same amount, but if the state of your database changed, it can result in different charges. That's a subtle distinction, but important to understand for more complex operations. For example, a find query that hits multiple shard keys will become more expensive as more physical shards are used to handle the data volume/throughput. .explain() can break down more details. That said, upsert shouldn't see big differences. Send me an email and I can look at backend telemetry to help: chrande@microsoft.com

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT - please refrain from starting out-of-band conversations. All related information to the question really needs to be here, on Stack Overflow, in the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to include information about the collection itself, such as the number of RU/sec allocated to your collection, partition key, etc.

Comment: @NoahStahl well, the record already exists in DB and the have pasted the above detail as what I had received from cosmos db shell.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I'm will mail you.

Comment: @Noobie - based on the additional information provided, I'm guessing that, due to the partitioning you have, your RU's are being distributed to a large number of partitions. Additionally, you enabled autoscale, which is likely going to provision more RU than you might actually need. This is why you're likely seeing a larger-than-expected RU/sec level for your collection. It also explains why the sudden drop-off in RU after you're done with your data load.